# Show other Stack Exchange accounts on the account creation confirmation page

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, openid

A user sent us a request to merge two accounts since they accidentally created an account with an OpenID that they didn't normally use for our network. (It's easy enough to merge in this case, so that's not the problem.) But then they suggested that at the final page before you create the account, we could show a list of other accounts you already have. For reference, the page looks something like:

[image: Confirm Your New Account]

If you happen to catch that you are using the wrong Gmail address (as I did above), you might stop the process short of creating an account that needs to be merged. But that's a little hard to spot. So this feature request is to add a box that lists your other accounts:

[image: Other accounts]

Importantly, if those credentials don't have any accounts on the network, the box would have a notice instead:

> **Other accounts not found.**

This won't prevent *every* user mistake of using the wrong credentials, but it would give people a fighting chance to notice their error before creating an account.

Comment: Whichever user suggested this idea must be incredibly talented and exceedingly handsome. (It was me)

Comment: Looks like one of those things which are really helpful yet really simple to do.

Comment: @Kai: Thank you for the suggestion. Normally I'd ask the person writing in to suggest it themselves. But this was too good not to ---steal--- get in front of the community right away. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good idea, but I think the phrasing of ***"Other accounts not found"*** needs work.

It sounds very negative and almost reads like an error message.  For a user with existing accounts and is familiar with Stack Exchange, it shouldn't a problem, but a vast majority of the users who get this message will probably be brand new to Stack Exchange, and I'd be worried that it would create confusion since it sounds like an error message.

If no accounts are found, then I think the message should be more of a reminder than an error message:

> We did not find any existing accounts on other Stack Exchange sites.  If you have accounts on other sites, then check you are using the correct OpenID

Comment: Ah, much better. The important thing is that it's got to be noticeable to people creating their second account without freaking out them out on their first account. I think your wording strikes the right balance.